# 2023 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election, moderators, announcement

[Moderator election #4](https://cs.stackexchange.com/election/4) on Computer Science has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Pseudonym]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/election/4) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5218089321889792).

Comment: Congratulations Pseudonym!! I am happy for the community!  

Answer (score 11):

Thank you to everyone who participated in the election! Looking forward to helping out in any way I can.

Answer (score 7):

Congratulations!  Thank you for volunteering to serve the community!  I feel fortunate that we'll have you on the moderation team.